# How to deal with elements that may or may not exist in UITableViewCell in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Suppose I'm writing a Twitter clone where users can post messages and photos. I'm rendering tweets in a UITableView. For tweets that have photo(s), I will put those photos in a UICollectionView, call it `photoCollectionView` and this UICollectionView is a subview of the cell. Problem is, what if a tweet doesn't have any photo? How could I hide `photoCollectionView` and set the cell height dynamically? I can think of 2 options so far:

**Option 1:** Make use of story board and auto layout. In my story board, add `photoCollectionView` anyway, but make its `height = 0`. However, I have to set up the constraints, because that's how I would be able to use `tweetTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`. Therefore, I set up top, left, right, height constraints for `photoCollectionView`. Then in `TweetCell` class I have:

```
class TweetCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var photoCollectionView: UICollectionView!

    var photos: [UIImage]? {
        didSet {
            if let assets = photos {
                photoCollectionView.delegate = self
                photoCollectionView.frame.size.height = <Some number>
            } else {
                photoCollectionView.frame.size.height = 0
            }
        }
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        photoCollectionView.delegate = nil
        photoCollectionView.frame.size.height = 0
    }
}

extension TweetCell: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    ...
}
```

**Option 2:** Do not add it in story board:

```
class TweetCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    private var photoCollectionView: UICollectionView?
    var photos: [UIImage]? {
        didSet {
            if let assets = photos {
                photoCollectionView = UICollectionView.init(...)
                photoCollectionView.delegate = self
            }
        }
    }

    // Then pretty much the same as above
}
```

Then later, in my `TweetTableViewController` where I render all tweets, I need to set up the row height manually:

```
override func cellHeightForRowAt (indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let cell = tweetTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? TweetCell
    if let photos = cell?.photos {
        return <Some number>
    }

    return 20    // Suppose default height is 20, to display other info
}
```

Both options give me what I want, **but is there a better way to do it? This way doesn't seem very performant:**

1. Option 1 uses `prepareForReuse`, according to [Developer Guide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623223-prepareforreuse), I should only reset attributes that are not related to content.
2. Option 2 adds the UICollectionView on the fly, what if a user scrolls fast?

Comment: Option 3:  Have two prototype cells.  One with tweets with photos, and one with tweets without photos.  Dequeue the appropriate cell based upon the data you have in `cellForRowAt`.

Comment: OMG, I haven't tried it yet but I'm sure you got it right!

Comment: Just give them different identifiers, then you just dequeue the one you want based upon the identifier.

Comment: @vacawama, I have no idea why I didn't think of that, I made use of multiple types of cells throughout the app. Thank you very much! If you post the answer below, I will accept it, unless you don't care about reputation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 3:** Have two prototype cells. One for tweets with photos, and one for tweets without photos. Dequeue the appropriate cell based upon the data you have in `cellForRowAt`.

Just give them different identifiers, then you just dequeue the one you want based upon the identifier.